# Calling Sql Server 2008 stored procedure from vb6 with datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, vb6, sql-server-2000

I have a legacy vb6 app which accesses databases running on both SQL2000 and SQL2008 databases.

When calling a stored procedure with a datetime parameter from vb6 using an `adDBTimeStamp` input parameter, the complete date time, including seconds is passed to the stored procedure.

When calling the same stored procedure in an SQL2008 r2 database, the seconds are always zero.

**EDIT**:

Create the following stored procedure on both a SQL2000 database and an SQL2008 R2 database.

```
CREATE    PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestDate] (@DateAndTime DATETIME)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    SELECT @DateAndTime AS DateAndTime
END
```

Then build a VB6 app with the following command button event method:

```vb
Private Sub Command_Click()

    Dim SQL2000_ConnectionString As String
    Dim SQL2008_ConnectionString As String
    Dim DateOnly As Date
    Dim DateAndTime As Date

    DateAndTime = DateTime.Now

    SQL2000_ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=<SQL2000ServerName>;UID=<UserName>;pwd=<Password>;Database=<DataBaseName>;dsn=''"
    SQL2008_ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Server=<SQL2008ServerName>;Database=<DataBaseName>;User Id=<UserName>;Password=<Password>;"

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Msg As String

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 300
    Call conn.Open(SQL2000_ConnectionString)

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        Set .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "TestDate"
        .CommandTimeout = 60
        Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@dtDateAndTime", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput))
        .Parameters("@dtDateAndTime").Value = DateAndTime
        Set rs = .Execute
    End With
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Msg = "DateTime:" & rs.fields("DateAndTime").Value
        Call MsgBox(Msg)
    End If
    Call conn.Close


    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 300
    Call conn.Open(SQL2008_ConnectionString)

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        Set .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "TestDate"
        .CommandTimeout = 60
        Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@dtDateAndTime", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput))
        .Parameters("@dtDateAndTime").Value = DateAndTime
        Set rs = .Execute
    End With
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Msg = "DateTime:" & rs.fields("DateAndTime").Value
        Call MsgBox(Msg)
    End If
    Call conn.Close


End Sub
```

When you execute the vb6 app, the first message box displays with the date and time including seconds. The second message box has the seconds display as zero.

I am seeing the same thing when I log the input parameters within the databases.

It appears as though the call to the SQL2008 R2 database is truncating the seconds of the input parameter.

**2nd EDIT**:

It appears that the OLE DB driver may be the culprit.
When I change to use the Native Client, it appears to work correctly.

```
SQL2008_ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=<SQL2008ServerName>;UID=<UserName>;pwd=<Password>;Database=<DataBaseName>;"
```

As this is a heavily used legacy app, and regression testing everything to use a new driver is time prohibitive. Is there any way to make the OLE DB driver do the correct thing?

**3rd EDIT**:

Just realized it is not a SQL 2008 R2 box. I was mistaken. It is just SQL2008

Here is my `@@VERSION`:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)
```

Comment: Assuming that is a question... can you post some code. The VB6 sie and the sprocs from both databases

Comment: Can you run SQL profiler to see the command that is executed against the 2008 DB?  I suspect the commands are the same and that your date column in 2008 is probably a SmallDateTime data type.  (just guessing).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Apparently the solution is to set the precision and numeric scale on the command object parameter to that of the defined size of addbTimeStamp.

Adding these two lines to the cmd object parameter before the call to the SQL2008 database, and the seconds are passed to the stored procedure.

```
    .Parameters("@dtDateAndTime").Precision = 23
    .Parameters("@dtDateAndTime").NumericScale = 3
```